# How to make express-session work on a cross-site setup (Cannot set a cookie from the backend to the frontend)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, express-session, render.com

How to make express-session work on a cross-site setup (Cannot set a cookie from the backend to the frontend)?

I created a test app as I am having a hard time finding ways to set cookies to the front end. When I try to set sameSite: 'none' and cookie: true, I cannot find the cookie in the header. But when I set the cookie to false and remove the sameSite, The cookie was in the header but it was blocked and i am getting an error such as I should set the sameSite=none and secure to true. The website is deployed at render.com.

The link of the react looks like this
https://react-websiteName-2d0w.onrender.com

The link of the server looks like this
https://api-websiteName-hj7g.onrender.com

```
//server
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const sessions = require('express-session');
const app = express();

const PORT = 3001;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://react-websiteName-2d0w.onrender.com',
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
    credentials: true
}));

const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
app.use(sessions({
    secret: "secret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: oneDay,
        sameSite:'none'
    },
    resave: false
}));

app.post('/createSession', (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = req.body.user;
    res.send('new session is created');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});



//react app
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post('https://api-websiteName-hj7g.onrender.com/createSession',
      { user: "user" }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Check if there is a cookie</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to make express-session work on my project when deployed with different domian.
Are there better alternatives or methods that could work in render.com instead of express-session?